# Media File format Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to create a simple media player with Qt, so I want to open some media files from a directory (which i already did) but i want to split audio files and video files from each other, put them in a playlist (listView) and display each one of them in a different tab.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You could show what you tried

Comment: Don't split audio from video to avoid lip sync.

Comment: @eyllanesc I already did with the screenshot!

Comment: @eyllanesc Ok, for example, you click the add button to load some media files, you choose a list that you want to play, if that list contains audio files it will be displayed just in the first(all) and third tab(audio) and if it contains video files, it will be displayed in the first(all) and the second tab(video).
So i think if i want to achieve that goal, i have to create a function that will verify the files extensions. but i do not know how to do it as a beginner.

Comment: @it4Astuces since as you point out you have shown an image of your project I assume you know how to get the path of the file, after that you should only use QFileInfo to get the suffix with the function [completeSuffix()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfileinfo.html#completeSuffix) and then just filter by extension(suffix)

Comment: Thank you for your replay, i will try to do it. Good luck and have a good day

Comment: @eyllanesc Do you know what are the Qt supported Multimedia formats files ?